# Preserving Bijectivity under pointwise limit

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

The following question I have tried to solve and have also tried to find reference for. A reference would be appreciated.

> Suppose that $f_i, g_i :\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ are continuous functions such that $f_i \circ g_i =g_i \circ f_i = \text{id}_\mathbb{R^n}$ for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\Omega_{\{f_i\}}$ be the set of points for which $\{f_i\}_i$ converges pointwise to some function, say $f$.  Similarly, let $\Omega_{\{g_i\}}$ be the set of points for which $\{g_i\}_i$ converges pointwise to some function, say $g$. Then show that $$f \circ g = \text{id}_{\Omega_{\{g_i\}}}$$ and  $$g \circ f = \text{id}_{\Omega_{\{f_i\}}}$$ specifically that such compositions make sense (i.e. that $\Omega_{\{f_i\}} \subseteq g(\Omega_{\{g_i\}})$  and $\Omega_{\{g_i\}} \subseteq f(\Omega_{\{f_i\}})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample on $\mathbb R^1:$ For $m=1,2,\dots,$ define

$$f_m(x)= \begin{cases}x,& x\le 0\\x^m,& 0<x<1\\ x,& x\ge 1\\\end{cases}$$

Then each $f_m$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R.$ Set $g_m= (f_m)^{-1},$ i.e.,

$$g_m(x)= \begin{cases}x,& x\le 0\\x^{1/m},& 0<x<1\\ x,& x\ge 1\\\end{cases}$$

Check that $f_m$ converges pointwise everywhere to the function $f$ that is $0$ on $(0,1)$ and is the identity elsewhere. Similarly, $g_m$ converges pointwise everywhere to the function $g$ that is $1$ on $(0,1)$ and is the identity elsewhere. We have $f\circ g=1$ on $(0,1),$ and $g\circ f=0$ on $(0,1),$ showing the desired conclusion does not hold.

Comment: Typo: $g \circ f = 0$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Indeed. Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true.

Let us first consider the following sequence of piecewise linear homeomorphisms on the unit interval $I = [0,1]$:
$$h_i(t) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{t}{i} & t \le \frac{1}{2}  \\
\frac{1}{2i}+2(1-\frac{1}{2i})(t-\frac{1}{2}) & t \ge \frac{1}{2} 
\end{cases}
$$
The inverse homeomorphisms are given by
$$h_i^{-1} =
\begin{cases}
ti & t \le \frac{1}{2i}  \\
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2(1-\frac{1}{2i})}(t-\frac{1}{2i}) & t \ge \frac{1}{2i} 
\end{cases}
$$
Obviosuly $(h_i)$ converges (even uniformly) to the continuous surjection
$$h : I \to I, h(t) =
\begin{cases}
0 & t \le \frac{1}{2}  \\
2(t-\frac{1}{2}) & t \ge \frac{1}{2} 
\end{cases}
$$
The sequence $(h_i^{-1})$ also converges pointwise on $I$. Its limit is
$$h^- : I \to I, h^-(t) =
\begin{cases}
0 & t = 0  \\
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}t  & t > 0
\end{cases}
$$
This is a non-continuous injection. We have $h \circ h^- = id$, but $h^- \circ h \ne id$.

To get examples on $\mathbb{R}^n$, define
$$f_i(x) =
\begin{cases}
x & \lVert x \rVert \ge 1  \\
h_i(\lVert x \rVert)x  & \lVert x \rVert \le 1
\end{cases}
$$